# Swift - Firestore Query Optional Values

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

so I'm working with boolean data for when content is uploaded to Firestore.

```
var isBlue: Bool = false
```

I've structured my code for when `isBlue` is false, I will not write the value to the database as I thought it's pretty useless and you get charged for writes.

So now I'm on to querying data, is it possible to query fields/keys that may not even exist to avoid & limit overhead?

I know I can do it on the client-side and filter data, however, this does result in unnecessary reads. Or would better practise be to just write each value to the database regardless if they're nil?

Comment: "is it possible to query fields/keys that may not even exist?" No, this is currently not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+query+non-existing+field (didn't find a good single answer yet). It's partially covered in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations under "Queries with a `!=` clause are not supported. "

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Cos I guess I just have to write the data regardless of the values to limit overhead. Swings and roundabouts I guess. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. I'll close against the link I provided for now.